# Vaadin: How do I make all fragment urls case insensitive

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, case-sensitive, case-insensitive, navigator

In Vaadin I add views to the navigator via a String like this:

```
navigator.addView("myView", CustomClass.class);
```

This is case-sensitive. So this works:

```
http://domain/#!myView
```

This does not work:

```
http://domain/#!myview
```

I want both urls to work and preferably make it completly case-insensitive. I could go and add the lower case version as well, but I would prefer a cleaner way that works for all cases. I already have users who know the current url with the upper case letter in it.

Is there a way to configure the navigator, so it works in a way that ignores the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new `ViewProvider`

```
import com.vaadin.navigator.View;
import com.vaadin.navigator.ViewProvider;

public class CaseInsensitiveClassBasedViewProvider implements ViewProvider {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String viewName;
    private final Class<? extends View> viewClass;

    public CaseInsensitiveClassBasedViewProvider(String viewName, Class<? extends View> viewClass) {
        if (null == viewName || null == viewClass) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "View name and class should not be null");
        }

        this.viewName = viewName;
        this.viewClass = viewClass;
    }

    @Override
    public String getViewName(String viewAndParameters) {
        if (null == viewAndParameters) {
            return null;
        }

        String viewAndParametersU = viewAndParameters.toUpperCase();
        String viewNameU = viewName.toUpperCase();

        if (viewAndParametersU.equals(viewNameU) || viewAndParametersU.startsWith(viewNameU + "/")) {
            return viewName;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(String viewName) {
        if (this.viewName.equalsIgnoreCase(viewName)) {
            try {
                View view = viewClass.newInstance();
                return view;
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then instead of adding with `addView` add with:

```
navigator.addProvider(new CaseInsensitiveClassBasedViewProvider("myView", CustomClass.class));
```